# Alert for character limitation in coldfusion gives multiple pop ups in IE 9

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, internet-explorer-9

I have a `textarea` in my form. I need to limit the number of characters in the `textarea` by giving a pop up message if the text in the field exceeds the limit. The following is the code I am using now. It works fine in FF, Chrome, and IE8, but not in IE9. In IE9 it gives unlimited pop ups if the limit is exceeded:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function limitText1(limitField,  limitNum) {
    if (limitField.value.length > limitNum) {
        limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0, limitNum);
        alert("Character limit exceeded--please reduce the length of description or use a file attachment.");
    }
}
```

```
<cftextarea
    style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;width:465px;" 
    onKeyDown="limitText1(this.form.description,16350);"
    OnInput="limitText1(this.form.description,16350);"
    onpropertychange="limitText1(this.form.description,16350);"
    required="yes"
    message="Please enter Description"
    class="textarea"
    id="description" 
    cols="75" rows="7" 
    name="description" 
    value="#form.description#"
></cftextarea>
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, given the text of your js alert, it looks like the contents of the textarea are going into an email body.  If that's the case, why do you need any limits at all?

Comment: The contents of the textarea are stored into the database..and  have a limit for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically don't use CFForm but...

instead of using

```
onKeyDown="limitText1(this.form.description,16350);"
OnInput="limitText1(this.form.description,16350);"
onpropertychange="limitText1(this.form.description,16350);"
```

try just using one, `onKeyDown` or `onPropertyChange`.  (onInput will not work for IE 8 or below).

Might not be the solution but it's worth a try, at least for trouble shooting.

Comment: Thanks Travis for your reply..but the code i pasted is working fine in IE8. Only IE9 is having issue.

Comment: Also i tried the events you told...onKeyDown is not alerting in IE9.But onPropertyChange alerts multiple times

Comment: I think this is because onPropertyChange triggers onBlur and onFocus as well as onKeyUp and down so when the alert is dismissed the focus property changes triggering another alert. I would try using onKeyUp and onBlur to test content that was pasted.

Comment: Yaa..i tried only with OnBlur. its working fine..but some delay in alerting..anyway that issue is fixed...Thanks Travis... :)

Answer (score 2):

cftextarea has a maxlenghth attribute.  Why don't you simply use it?

If you want to tell the user that he reached the maximum number of characters, you can write a simple js function to do that and call it in the onblur event.  It's a lot simpler than what you are currently attempting.

Comment: Maxlength is a good way anyway....but requirement is giving the alert....so could you please give an example for function..

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="Javascript">
String.prototype.trim = function() {return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");}

    function check_limit(comment_txt, limit_txt,count)
    {

        var tex = document.getElementById(comment_txt).value;
        var len = tex.length;
        if((tex.trim() != '') && (len > count))
        {
                tex = tex.substring(0,count);
                alert("Limit Exceeded");
                document.getElementById(comment_txt).value =tex.trim();
                document.getElementById(limit_txt).value =count-tex.trim().length;
                return false;
        }
        else if(tex.trim() == '')
            document.getElementById(comment_txt).value =tex.trim();
        document.getElementById(limit_txt).value =count-document.getElementById(comment_txt).value.length;
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.